# How do I get time zone support for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, timezone, utc

I've just begun attempting to use UTC on MySQL and it seems that my download did not include a timezone file and doesn't support it (it shows up as NULL).

I've looked around the MySQL website for a way to get timezone support loaded, but I can't seem to find anything.

Can someone walk me through the process or tell me whether there's a file I should import? I've already seen the manual pages, but it doesn't seem to apply to my situation.

Thanks!

Comment: Iirc MySQL uses the timezone of the system it runs on. Also there is the option `time zone` which can be set.

Comment: Check out the MySQL manual here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html

Comment: Great. That link was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do?

The usual way would be to ignore timezone issues when you're storing things in the database. Put them in as timestamps, which will be timezone-agnostic (i.e., they'll be the time in UTC). When you want to *display* something in your application, you will need to retrieve the timestamp from the database and display it according to the appropriate timezone for the machine it's running on.